# Create right floating image in PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

I want an image on the right, text on the left floating around the image. The other way round works pretty good, there also is an example for that on the [Recipies section in the documentation](http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html). However, I did not get this working with images floating on the right. What I tried:

```
addImage('myimage.png', 
   array(
       'width'=>320, 
       'height'=>240, 
       'align'=>'right',
       'wrappingStyle'=>'square',
       'positioning' => 'absolute'
   )
);
```

or

```
addImage('myimage.png', 
   array(
       'width'=>320, 
       'height'=>240, 
       'align'=>'right',
       'wrappingStyle'=>'square',
       'positioning' => 'absolute',
       'posHorizontalRel' => 'margin',
       'posVerticalRel' => 'line'
   )
);
```

I also experimented with negative image widths etc., but that did not work neither. Unfortunately, documentation on the whole project is really poor, at least at [phpword.readthedocs.org](http://phpword.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem too, and there's no answer on the internet to this date. So here's what I came up with:

```
$section->addImage('image.png', array(
    'width' => 40,
    'height' => 40,
    'wrappingStyle' => 'square',
    'positioning' => 'absolute',
    'posHorizontal'    => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
    'posHorizontalRel' => 'margin',
    'posVerticalRel' => 'line',
));
```

Comment: YES - Exactly what I was looking for. Fun fact, you can use "page" instead of margin ;)